# is there a way to use the native messaging app, on android, in my own app?

Tags: java, android

One of the pages in my app needs to be the same as the native messaging app. That is have all of the uses messages and be able to send and receive sms messages.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to just launch the SMS app?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way. The only method you can try is to launch the Messaging App, but I dont think that this is what you want.

Comment: Opening the messaging app is not what i need. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. How ever you can launch a share intent if you want to share data from your app to the other app. Other than that there is nothing you can do to include it in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it.  You can launch the messaging app.  But on modern Android, only the default SMS app can receive SMS messages.  Not to mention-  every phone out there has a different "native SMS app" on it, so there's no way to make an app look like it.